# Correct way to install singularity with bower?

Tags: sass, yeoman, gulp, yeoman-generator, singularitygs

I'm running in some troubles installing singularity in my [yeoman gulp-webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp) project. First, I installed singularity with bower.

After that I had a projekt structure like this:

```
  My Projekt
    app
       bower_components
         compass_breakpoint
         sassy-maps 
         singularity
       styles
         main.scss
```

Then I imported singularity into my *main.scss* file like this:

```
@import "../bower_components/singularity/stylesheets/singularitygs";
```

In _*singularity.scss* I corrected the import path for *breakpoint* to:

```
@import "../../compass-breakpoint/stylesheets/breakpoint";
```

If I run `gulp`now in the terminal I get this strange error:

```
[gulp] Error in plugin 'gulp-ruby-sass':
Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "...ntext holder') ": expected "}", was "!global;"
    on line 47 of  /Users/Shared/Dropbox/Server/htdocs/Frameworks/my-project/app/bower_components/compass-breakpoint/stylesheets/_breakpoint.scss
    from line 4 of /Users/Shared/Dropbox/Server/htdocs/Frameworks/my-project/app/bower_components/singularity/stylesheets/_singularitygs.scss
    from line 1 of /Users/Shared/Dropbox/Server/htdocs/Frameworks/my-project/app/styles/main.scss

at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/Shared/Dropbox/Server/htdocs/Frameworks/my-project/node_modules/gulp-ruby-sass/index.js:80:25)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:956:11)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
```

Did anyone have an idea how to get this setup running?

Thanks, Oli

Answer (score 0):

While you can install Singularity through Bower, you need to make sure you're running a compiler that's compatible with Sass 3.3. The best way to ensure you are in fact using the correct version of Sass is to version your Ruby with [Bundler](http://bundler.io/). Your Gemfile should look something like the following:

`source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem "sass", "~>3.3.0.rc.3"`

Then make sure that Gulp Ruby Sass is running through [`bundleExec`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass#bundleexec)

Comment: Ok, I installed *singularity* with bundler and updated my *gulpfile.js* 
with `bundleExec: 'bundle exec sass',`    

In my *main.scss* I imported *singularity* with @import "singularitygs";`  

But if I run `grunt watch`now I get this error:  

`[gulp] Error in plugin 'gulp-ruby-sass':
Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: singularity's.`